# Dynamics CRM - call javascript resource

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

We are in the process of migrating our data to CRM online.
I would like to run some javascript code that I have that creates the sharepoint folder for an entity when the page loads.
However as we are using an api to create the record from existing data, is there a way to call/trigger the javascript on record create?

Comment: See if this could be helpful: http://www.powerobjects.com/2013/02/04/bulk-creation-of-sharepoint-folders-dynamics-crm/

Answer (score 0):

There is no hook for JavaScript with Dynamics CRM to trigger an action when a record is created, however the following may work (although is a little messy!).

1) Create a new dummy field (hidden, but on every the form) called "SharePoint Created?", this is a two options field, default value of "No".

2) Create a new JavaScript function to execute on "Form Load", which checks the form type to ensure its in edit mode (not create), if so, checks the value for the "SharePoint Created?" field, if this field is "No", update it to "Yes", call your SharePoint creation function, then save the record.

The better option would be to the move the call to a Plugin, which can be executed on create of a record, but understand authentication is always a problem.

Comment: Thank you for the response.
The problem is there are 15000 records being migrated and we dont want to have to open every record.

Comment: dont have to open each one- using the XRMToolbox each record can be touched to trigger an event, or since you only want to do this for migration a flow or logicApp would also be an option